# How can we build a sentence for presumed past in German?

Tags: grammar-identification

I have a sentence which would say

> - Had I won this lottery money 10 years before, I would have saved my mother from illness.
> - If WhatsApp was invented 30 years before, I would have saved a lot of money in ISD calls.

These are presumed past. I read about Future 2 which builds sentence for presumed future.

To build these kind of sentences which past form should we use? I could not relate Perfekt, Präteritum or Plusquamperfekt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need the [subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood), in this case the [Konjunktiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktiv) II:

- Hätte ich vor 10 Jahren im Lotto gewonnen, hätte ich meine Mutter vor Krankheit bewahrt.
- Wäre WhatsApp 30 Jahre früher erfunden worden, hätte ich viel Geld für Ferngespräche gespart.

Comment: how to build sentence for the "would have". This is the main area I need help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure this gave me a new idea.

Comment: German differs here from English in that it uses the same verb form for both clauses (Konjunktiv II).

Comment: "Vor Krankheit bewahren". Also, in the original answer I'd translate "30 years before" to "30 Jahre früher".

Comment: "Vor Krankheit schützen" is probably the most common term.